# Как сделать клик по кнопке если разрешение экрана меньше 1600px

Tags: javascript

Как сделать клик по кнопке, если разрешение экрана по ширине меньше `1600px`?

```html
<button onclick="hideme(this)" class="close">X - Закрыть?</button>
```

Comment: на js проверять размеры экрана перед нажатием https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window, или css через media запросы скрывать кнопки http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Comment: В этом коде если ширина менее заданной выполнить скрипт. Как сверстать чтобы сделать клик ?    function resizeScrenn(){
        if ($(window).width() <= 779){
        $(".icn-nav").click(function(){
            $('.navigation').fadeIn();
          });
          $(".icn-close").click(function(){
            $('.navigation').fadeOut();
          });
       } else{
          $('.navigation').fadeIn();
       } 
      }
      resizeScrenn();
      $(window).resize(function(){
       resizeScrenn();
      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так, (если кнопка с таким классом одна/первая):

```
check = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1600) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0].click()
    }
}

document.onload = check;
window.onresize = check;
```

Comment: Если зашли с ноутбука и разрешение экрана менее 1600px сделать клик по кнопке Или окно браузера сжали менее 1600 пикселей

Comment: @Helpsetup поправил ответ, но вы имейте ввиду, что это лишь пример. В какой момент следует выполнять такую проверку - вам виднее (её нужно обернуть функцией и положить в нужные ивенты, например **window.onresize**).

Comment: Если Я это еще знал как ))) В какой момент пр изменении ширины окна браузера

Comment: Этот трюк всегда сработает? Когда-то мне надо было эмулировать нажатия и оказалось, что Сафари игнорирует программные нажатия, если до этого не было какого-то пользовательского ввода.

Comment: @vusaldev никогда о подобном ограничении не слышал. может быть оно и есть, нужно проверять, но в таком случае Сафари намерено делает решение задачи невозможным (по крайней мере без костылей).

Comment: @vusaldev хотя можно конечно и не через клик, а вызвать функцию напрямую. я думаю, тут автор уже сам разберётся, как ему лучше)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через matchMedia API

````
// Что хотим сделать
function eventHandler(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        div.addClass("some-class");
    } else {
        div.classList.add('sss')
    }
}

// Разрешение которое отслеживаем.
const mq = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 768px)')

// вешаем event
mq.addListener(eventHandler)

// проверяем при старте
eventHandler(mq)```
````

Comment: Я только с div что то не пойму с этим API Это что за что отвечает, если взять мой случай ?  div.addClass("some-class");
    } else {
        div.classList.add('sss')